# add search engine to html using php

Tags: php, html, search-engine

How do we add a search engine to `index.html` to search the contents of the web page?

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">
</head>
```

This was the code present in w3schools meta tag page.
This one gives output as a blank screen.
I have created a html file

```
<head>
    <form action="demo_form.php">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</head>
```

This gives this [*output*](http://prntscr.com/77zo0v).

Where could I study searching code? Is it possible in php?

Comment: It is possible you'll need a database with all the site data though; or the data you want to search.

Comment: Where is the form method in your form???

Comment: Take the form content in the `<head>` tag to a `<body>` tag, and by _searching_ you mean querying the database?

Comment: yes querying the database, and returning the files in the FTP server, or hard disk, which has the keywords being searched

Comment: @saty the meta tag code was from the w3schools tutorial. It didn't have tutorial on forms. Is it mandatory to have "<meta>" tag for a search engine?

Comment: @someOne thanks for "querying database", I got a google result from the php.net 
resource mysql_db_query ( string $database , string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
EDITED TO ADD: Do we need MySql? but I have the files which are to be searched in my hard disk in the folder containing "index.htm"

Comment: Please avoid using the monstrous `mysql_*`s, instead try [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) :)

Comment: You may do whatever you want using PHP, but your question is so so broad (using SQL, using FileSystem, maybe regular expression,...) that each one is the topic of a book!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is bad for many reasons: 1) the author doesn't have a clue what he is doing. 2) the question does not make sense. 3) the author needs reading material and this is not the place to ask for it. FOR THE AUTHOR: yes, searching in-site is possible, but you have a lot to learn about web designing and programming before attempting to understand it.